# Problem in getting file path within the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file

Everyone

I am working on an app that supports viewing of document files (doc, text and others). As I have registered my app for these file types, If someone emails a document file to me, I use
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to get path of the file. Now problem is that what if the application is already running in background? How will I get the file path that caused my app to become active for opening that file?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

use "application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:" from the app delegate;  the following text is taken from Apple's documentation

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Discussion
If an application is launched as a result of another application requesting it to open a URL resource, UIApplication first sends the application a application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: message and then it invokes this method. This method supplies the delegate of the handling application with the bundle ID of the source application as well as any annotation information from that application. If an application is already running when it receives a request to open a URL, this method is called but application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn’t.

If this method is not implemented, UIApplication calls application:handleOpenURL: (if implemented). You should implement this method in preference to application:handleOpenURL:.

There is no matching notification for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want to open the document in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` anyway but in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` or `application:handleOpenURL:`.

From the docs:

> If your application is already running
>   when a document request arrives, the
>   sequence of events depends on your
>   delegate implementation and the
>   current version of iOS. In iOS 4.2,
>   the
>   application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
>   method is called and is expected to
>   check the document and open it. If
>   your delegate does not implement that
>   method, or if your application is
>   running in iOS 4.1 and earlier, only
>   the application:handleOpenURL: method
>   is called.